# Java Bson Library Fails to Map Document Object

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, mongodb-java, bson

I am using mongodriver to run some aggregation methods on Java, however bson library fails to map Document instance, though I am not sure if its in fact the reason.

Error I'm receiving:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/Document
        at services.ApplianceServiceImpl.aggregate(ApplianceServiceImpl.java:361)
        at controllers.AdminController.aggregate(AdminController.java:394)
```

BSON and Mongodriver declarations in SBT file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia" % "0.108",
  "org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia-logging-slf4j" % "0.108",
  "org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia-validation" % "0.108",
  "org.mongodb" % "bson" % "3.0.4",
  "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver" % "3.0.4",
```

Java Code:

```
public PaginationWrapper aggregate(FormRequest formData){
    List r = new ArrayList();
    int c=0;
    try{
        List l = asList(new Document("$group", new Document("_id", formData.field).append("count", new Document("$sum", 1))));
        Iterator i = db.getCollection(formData.collection).aggregate(l).results().iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()){
            r.add(i.next());
            c++;
        }
    }catch (Error e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new PaginationWrapper(c, r);
}
```

Code fails at line starting with '**List l = asList(new ...**'

What do you think I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The run-time throws this exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` because it didn't find a definition for `org.bson.Document` class in your classpath. In other words, `org.bson.Document` does not exists. Playframework adds all the jars found in `lib/` directory (I found mine under `MyPlayApplication\target\universal\stage\lib`). Try the following:

1. check if you can find the `bson-3.x.x.jar`.
2. In case you didn't find it, it means `sbt` file is incorrectly configured.
3. Try adding `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal` in `build.sbt`. Also make sure if the dependencies version number is correct.